# Nativescript TextField Password masked symbol turns to fireplace icon

Tags: ios, iphone, nativescript

Nativescript TextField Password masked symbol turns to fireplace icon. I have encountered this weird symbol/icon(fireplace icon) when iOS was updated into iOS 14.0+ and 14.4. But in iOS 13.5 version iphone it does show the dot instead of fireplace. [image]

Currently using nativescript 6.5

Here is the nativescript code:

```
<TextField hint="Password" secure="true"></TextField>
```

Comment: Do you use some specific fonts for your application?

Comment: yes, I use fontawesome font